# Class Not Responding To Int From A Diffrent Class

Tags: java, eclipse

This Might be a Dumb Question But

I Have This Code Here

```
    public class Main {
public static int choice;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ...
    //Get Input
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.print("Choose The Number!");
  int choice = reader.nextInt();
```

I Have Another Class, That  Want To Interact with the int, choice

```
   public class DevSetting {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if( Main.choice == 4 ){
System.out.print("Testing");
        }
}

        }
```

But When I Type '4' The Program Gets Terminated, but I Think That It Might Not Be The Actual code, It Could be How I Setup the project.

Anyway Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're shadowing the choice variable, meaning that you're re-declaring the variable within a method or constructor so that any changes made to the inner variable will not be reflected in the class field.
2. Your programs should have only one main method, and only one will run, so even if you didn't shadow the variable, your 2nd class would not work, would not successfully get the new choice value.
3. Your code formatting is a bit random, especially your code indentation style, and this makes your code very difficult for us to read and understand. Good formatting including using an indentation style that is uniform and consistent will help others (**us**!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, it will help **you** to better understand your code and thus fix your own bugs. Also it shows that you're willing to put in extra effort to make it easier for the volunteers here to help you, and that effort is **much** appreciated.

Better would be to create a public method in the second class, something like

```
public class DevSetting {

    public static void doSomething(int choice) {
        if( choice == 4 ){
            System.out.print("Testing");
        }
    }
}
```

Then this method could be called by the first class via:

```
DevSetting.doSomething(choice);
```

passing the changed choice information into this method.